# How to configure yum to support https

Tags: centos, yum, https

I am trying to configure yum 3.4.3 to support HTTPS on my CentOS 7.
Currently I am getting the following error when trying to update an application with `yum clean all; yum update myApp`.

The error:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from myRepo_123: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mydomain.com:8080/Files/yum/myRepo_123/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 301 - Moved Permanently
```

The reason for the redirection is that the port 8080 is being listened to by an nginx server and the server redirects the request to `https://mydomain.com:8443/Files/yum/myRepo_123/repodata/repomd.xml`

The redirection is on purpose for backward compatibility reasons so it has to stay.

From what I have read, yum can be configured to support https by setting the following 2 properties in `/etc/yum.conf` or in each repository file separately:

```
sslverify=1
sslcacert=/certs/rootCA.crt
```

I tried also those 2, even though I don’t think that they are needed:

```
sslclientcert=/certs/client.crt
sslclientkey=/certs/client.key
```

I have tried to change the settings in both places (stated above) but the same error remains.

I tested my certificate in the following way:

```
curl --cacert /certs/rootCA.crt -L http://mydomain.com:8080/Files/yum/myRepo_123/repodata/repomd.xml
```

The file is retrieved. Meaning the certificate that I am providing is valid.

When I change the address of the repository in `/etc/yum.repos.d/myRepo_123.repo` to the https one to avoid the redirection it works.

But how do I configure it with the redirection?

P.S – it works with the redirection when I am adding the certificate as a trusted authority using "update-ca-trust", but I am not allowed to that according to our system architect.

What am I missing?

Comment: You do not need client certificates, they are for mutual authentication. Comment them and try again

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks for your reply. I have commented out the client part, unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Check again the certificate because you retrieve it from http, not https. And add in repo file https.

Comment: @RomeoNinov the certificate is valid. Once i change the repo file to https address it works (as i wrote in the question). I am trying to understand if there is a way for me not to change the address in the repo file and make it work with the redirect.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thank you for your help. We decided to change the address in the repo file to https and stop trying to make the redirect work.